# Shouldn't it be "sagas and song"?

Tags: countability, countable-nouns

I find this sentence from a book odd:

> Their flimsy settlements consequently were soon abandoned, and their discovery was forgotten, **except in Scandinavian saga and song**.

According to both the Macmillan Dictionary and Cambridge English Dictionary, the word **saga** is a count noun. I know **song** can be a mass noun to refer to the idea or activity of singing. So isn't the sentence ungrammatical as written? Shouldn't it be edited to:

> Their flimsy settlements consequently were soon abandoned, and their discovery was forgotten, **except in Scandinavian sagas and song**.

Comment: The sentence is referring to the *class* of record in which their discovery is recorded. **...except in...sagas and songs** would also be viable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Saga can be a mass noun for the genre of Norse myth.

> Settings in saga are but sparse literalisms of terrain: the terse topography of ridge, grazing-ground, woodland clearing or marsh-land.
>   From [*Poetry, Space, Landscape: Toward a New Theory*](https://books.google.com/books?id=PJ-ojL7B66wC&pg=PA158&lpg=PA158&dq=%22Settings%20in%20saga%20are%20but%20sparse%20literalisms%20of%20terrain%22&source=bl&ots=KW93aHEK6F&sig=SmUUQ2Uobix-rB6W8iOxoMN9Vog&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKrKyK4NXaAhUHVK0KHbvwBYMQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22Settings%20in%20saga%20are%20but%20sparse%20literalisms%20of%20terrain%22&f=false) by Chris Fitter

Comment: +1 I think this is probably the answer. Btw, I edited in the source.

Comment: Also this applies to myth, legend, romance, opera, drama, and probably others. A drama or the genre of drama. A fiction is a little obsolete.